# Share data globally and render it in LitElement

Tags: lit-element

I'm trying to design a simple alert/notification system in LitElement exactly like http://bootstrap-notify.remabledesigns.com/ in which wherever you are in the application you can call `$.notify()` and show a notification.
The problem looks simple, but it's kind of tricky: you have to share a list of messages overall the WebComponents in the app. In every part of the app, inside a LitElement WC, the user should be able to do something simple like `NotificationInstance.push("my new message")`. I came up with this solution:

```
// singleton class which is supposed to be shared in all the WCs that need to use the notification system
export class NotificationQueue {
    constructor() {
        if (!NotificationQueue.instance) {
            NotificationQueue.instance = this;
        }
        this.queue = [];
        return NotificationQueue.instance;
    }

    setContext(context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    push(message) {
        this.queue = [...this.queue, message];
        this.context.requestUpdate();
    }

    remove(title) {
        this.queue = this.queue.filter( item => item.title !== title);
        this.context.requestUpdate();
    }
    get() {
        return this.queue;
    }

}

export class NotificationElement extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            queue: {
                type: Object
            }
        };
    }
    render(){
        return html`LIST: ${JSON.stringify(this.queue)}` //Stringify is just an example, this component will render the notifications properly
    }
}
```

In the main component of my app

```
class MyApp extends LitElement {
    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        new NotificationQueue().setContext(this);
    }
   render() {
      return html`
        -- content of the app --
        <notification-element .queue="${(new NotificationQueue()).get()}"></notification-element>`;
   }
}
```

How does this approach sound to you? The problem here is *how to force a `refreshUpdate()` to `NotificationElement` without calling `refreshUpdate()` to the **whole application***.
`setContext(this)` is indeed the context of the main LitElement class

Comment: I think you might want to take a look at the approach the [`connect-mixin` from pwa-helpers](https://github.com/Polymer/pwa-helpers/blob/master/src/connect-mixin.ts) takes, this depends on redux but you might easily achieve something similar without the redux dependency

Comment: I'm not sure how that is supposed to help in this context, are you suggesting I should implement an observer pattern for this? Anyway I edited my question with a functioning solution, the part I don't really like is  `this.context.requestUpdate();` In which I force an Update to the whole application..

Answer (score 0):

i recommend mixins

i've figured a pattern where during initialization: i prepare my single source-of-truth model of the state, and then i grab my components, but right before i register those components to the dom, i divide the state up into relevant shares, and distribute those [shares to each component](https://github.com/chase-moskal/metalshop/blob/30eb8c8bdbc3d0851149ac18d52a1cacdb50f582/source/startup/wire-component-shares.ts#L47) using a mixin

and so my components have access the `share` provided to them, and might be so lucky as to find a `notificationsQueue`, or something like that, and maybe with methods to read or write page-level notifications

mixins are a great way to manipulate components, of course statically with decorators, but lets not forget we can also use mixins to apply something more dynamic, like some state during initialization, before components have been registered

mixins are a great way to theme components too, like with [`@mixinStyles`](https://github.com/chase-moskal/metalshop/blob/30eb8c8bdbc3d0851149ac18d52a1cacdb50f582/source/framework/mixin-styles.ts#L21) i've been using a lot recently for lit-element